# Laravel: Save uuidv4 to database

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm using **React** and **Laravel** for the creation of a list.
In the add button I have the following

```
 function handleAdd() {
    const newList = list.concat({ name, id: uuidv4(), value });
    setList(newList);
    setName("");
    setValue("");
  }

const onAddSocial = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

const test = {
  value: value,
  name: name,
};

axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/social', test)
  .then((res) => {
    toast(<div class="text-primary font-weight-bolder">Social link added successfully!</div>,{ delay: 0 });
    console.log(res)
  }).catch((error) => {console.log(error)
  })

}
```

And the button to trigger both functions for the creation :

```
 <Button                  
                onClick={(e) => {
                  props.handleAdd();
                  props.onAddSocial(e);
                }}
              >
```

The element is created, but in the datatabse the `id` receive an incremented value. **How do I pass the uuidv4() of the created element instead ?**

The store controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = new Social();
    $data->value = $request->value;
    $data->name = $request->name;
    $data->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use following code

In your **Social Model** you have to use like this

```
public $incrementing = false;

protected $keyType = 'string';


public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($social) {
        $social->id = Str::uuid(36);
    });
}
```

Add this line in header section

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

In your **database\migration** social file add below code also

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('socials', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id', 36)->primary();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```