# Laravel 8 How to seed using Factories with UUID primary key?

Tags: laravel, factory

I have a Edtions and Issues tables, with a one to many relationship (issues N-1 editions).

When I try to call the `create()` method on my Issue factory I get a NOT NULL violation:

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, 1, 12011981, null, 2021-09-01 23:09:17, 2021-09-01 23:09:17, null). (SQL: insert into "issues" ("id", "issuing_date", "edition_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (?, 12011981, 1,
> 2021-09-01 23:09:17, 2021-09-01 23:09:17)).

**However I am specifying an ID my Issue Factory:**

```
class IssueFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Issue::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $timestamp = mt_rand(1, time());
        $randomDate = date("dmY", $timestamp);

        return [
            'id' => Str::uuid(),
            'issuing_date' => $randomDate,
            'edition_id' => 1,
        ];
    }
}
```

**My Seeder:**

```
public function run()
{
    Edition::each(function ($edition) {
       Issue::factory()
          ->count(10)
          ->for($edition)
          ->create();
    });
}
```

**Issues table migration:**

```
Schema::create('issues', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->integer('edition_id');
    $table->string('issuing_date');

    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();

    $table->foreign('edition_id')->references('id')->on('editions');
});
```

**relevant part of Issue model:**

```
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $table = 'issues';
    protected $keyType = "string";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $fillable = [
        "id",
        "edition_id",
        "issuing_date"
    ];
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use like below in your `Schema`

```
$table->uuid('id', 36)->primary();
```

In your model use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

public $incrementing = false;

protected $keyType = 'string';

public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($issue) {
        $issue->id = Str::uuid(36);
    });
}
```

This below line also add in your factory

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67239813/laravel-save-uuidv4-to-database/67239965#67239965)